# How do you run a Java UI application as a Group Custom User Inteface for windows (Possibly using Group Policies)?

Tags: java, windows, windows-shell, gpo

I've tried setting the Custom User Interface GPO option to

java -jar GyroUI.jar

as well as using the full path

C:\Program Files\jre7\bin\java.exe -jar GyroUI.jar

But neither seem to result in anything except the desktop background.

I know this works normally as I can run the jar file just fine using the command prompt, and I get the UI as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\Program Files\jre7\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files\Sahara\GyroUI.jar"

Ended up being the solution, the problem was being caused by the application crashing, not by the shell failing to launch.